# GMAP3 and Autocomplete: Restrict results?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-gmap3

I'm using the autocomplete function on [gMap3's website](http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html) to create an autocomplete search. I have it working, however I would like to restrict the autocomplete results to just one state (i.e., Missouri). Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for: http://gmap3.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=337#p1162

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `region` parameter of the `address` object of gMap.

```
address: {
    address: address,
    region: 'your region code'
}
```

This will give you better results, but it will not remove the wrong ones.
I'm not sure if it works with US states, or only whole countries.

I had the same problem. In the end I used this parameter, and appended a custom string to every request I send to the google API.

In your case just add "Missouri US" to the text from autocomplete before it is send to the google geocoder api.

Something like:

```
$('#element').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var requestTerm = 'Missouri US' + request.term; 

        $('#gmap').gmap3(
            {action:'getAddress',
                address: {
                    address: requestTerm,
                    region: 'your region code'
            }
        );
    ...
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works fine.